# How to upload image in same form with other features to database?

Tags: php, mysql

This is my code and I want to upload images along with other info like email password etc. but it is not working.

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
include("include/connect.php");
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $repassword = $_POST['repassword'];
        $sql="INSERT INTO student ('name', 'email',    'password','repassword','pic')
        VALUES ('name' , 'email' ,'password' ,'repassword' ,'pic')";

        $res=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        var_dump($res);

    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    } 
}
?>
```

This is my code and it is not working.

#### Edit

[<sup>From a comment by OP</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29624107/how-to-upload-image-in-same-form-with-other-features-to-database#comment47392150_29624107)

```
<form action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="insert" method="post" name="insert">
    USERNAME:<input name="name" type="text" value=""><br>
    EMAIL-ID:<input name="email" type="text" value=""><br>
    PASSWORD:<input name="password" type="password" value=""><br>
    RE-PASSWORD:<input name="repassword" type="password" value=""><br>
    <br>
    <input id="fileToUpload" name="fileToUpload" type="file"><br>
    <input name="hdn" type="hidden" value="hdn"><br>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit"><br>
</form>
```

Comment: What is "not working", exactly?

Comment: Please add the code of the form (html).

Comment: **WARNING:** There is no evidence of binding parameters, data validation or sanitization. Good luck with your SQL injections @Uthman

Comment: Exact problem is data is not going to database and query etc are correct according to the best of my knowledge

Comment: <form name="insert" method="post" action="upload.php"  enctype="multipart/form-data">

USERNAME:<input type="text" name="name" value=""></br>
EMAIL-ID:<input type="text" name="email" value=""></br>
PASSWORD:<input type="password" name="password" value=""></br>
RE-PASSWORD:<input type="password" name="repassword" value=""></br><br>
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"></br>
<input type = "hidden" name = "hdn" value = "hdn">
<br>
      
<input type="submit" name = "submit" value = "submit"><br>
      </form>

Comment: this is the form code

Comment: Thank you all of you brothers,i did it

Answer (score 0):

Your query is incorrect on 2 points;

- You're quoting column names
- You're using static values *(incorrect because in this scenario, your values should be dynamic)*

#### Quoting column names

The following will result in a query error - thus your query will not execute and a record will be inserted into the database.

```
INSERT INTO student ('name', 'email','password','repassword','pic')
```

If you want to quote your column names, use a backtick (`).

```
INSERT INTO student (`name`, `email`,`password`,`repassword`,`pic`)
```

#### Static values

You're inserting static values. Use your variables.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO student (`name`, `email`,    `password`,`repassword`,`pic`)
        VALUES ('{$name}' , '{$email}' ,'{$password}' ,'{$repassword}' ,'{$pic}')";
```

**NOTE:** This is *very* insecure, and you should be;

- Validating ***all*** user input
- Sanitizing input
- Binding your parameters
- Read [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) and [this OWASP article](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)

Comment: Thank you and i tried all that but still the result is futile

Comment: Okay, please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29624107/how-to-upload-image-in-same-form-with-other-features-to-database/29624613?noredirect=1#comment47391824_29624107

Answer (score -1):

check below function if there is any error in your query.

```
mysqli_error($con);
```

Use below code to upload a file.

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {<br/>
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has <br/>been uploaded.";
    } else {<br/>
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";<br/>
    }
```

Comment: What about the MySQL errors? The query is incorrect.

Comment: Also i change the form code to the above , given by OP but not working

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$target_file' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\snipp\upload.php on line 5

Comment: Thanks to all of you brothers,,i did it